# How do i schedule alarms in aws cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

I have a few alarms set up with an evaluation period of 5 minutes.

The problem is that I get too many alerts throughout the day because of them getting triggered. Is there a way to schedule those alarms once a day or twice a day?

Comment: What about setting the evaluation period to 24h?

Comment: Even if I set the evaluation to 24 hrs wouldnt it get triggered as soon as the threshold reaches its point?

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch Alarms only trigger when the cross the threshold. They will not send another alarm until they return to the `OK` status and then cross into `ALARM` again.

So, if you are receiving multiple alarms, is because they are often going into, and out of, the `ALARM` state.

If this is too sensitive for your needs, increase the **evaluation period** or the number of **number of datapoints** required to trigger the alarm.